# Multiple Music Player that Resumes when you come back to site, not go back to beginning

Tags: multithreading

I have multiple music player on a website.

If I put it on shuffle, I hear the same songs over and again - not a true shuffle of the whole deck.

If I have it on non-shuffle, it *always* starts at the beginning of the playlist (of 500 songs) again.

*I want a multiple music player that resumes right where it left off.* Is that possible?  Then it would be *non-shuffle*. Could you kindly guide me in that direction?

Comment: **1**. Please don't use caps, you don't need to yell. **2**. What language/framework are you using? **3**. Do you have a music player you want help with or are you asking for one?

Comment: This is the one i am using www.karenkellock.org.  I want it on shuffle but keep hearing same songs.  So either a fix or a new one as per your suggestions.

Comment: That link only goes to what I assume is your website. You need to link to the actual music players website (its product page, documentation or whatever) if you want help with it.

Comment: I don't know how to do that--any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you implemented it on your website so you must've found it somewhere. I'm afraid I can't help you anymore since it's not enough information to go on. I'd recommend using another music player that you know have these functions supported. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know cuz I always have tech guys install things and it goes back too many years.   Alright can you or anyone please DIRECT me to a good multi-music player with resume and run-thru-the-deck shuffle?  THE BEST?

Comment: You have probably a better chance of finding one than me, I have no knowledge of music players sorry. Try searching for "*html web music players*" and you might find some.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XviGa3fZzTQ----WOULD THIS BE IT??

Comment: I don't know, like I said earlier, I have no specific knowledge about music players.